# difficulty setting my yahoo chat id - can't find the option

Tags: yahoo-messenger

NOTE: This is not a web application question. Yahoo instant messenger is a standalone application.

I use yahoo instant messenger, and have a problem that when I chat, the username that comes up is the first part of my email address.

when I make a friend request, the name that the other person sees is a full name..

i'd like to know where -both- those settings are particularly the one that determines what comes up in the chat window, since I don't want it to be the first part of my email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to Yahoo Messenger, then clicked Messenger and "My Account Info"

I then got this page

You want to click Manage yahoo aliases.  It's not the same as the yahoo aliases in email options.

Once you add them there, you can log in as any, or in a chat window just above where you type a message, you cah choose "send as" and choose any of them.

> **Profile Information**
>   Edit profile details       <--- not this one
>
> **Contact Information**
>   Update your contact information       <--- not this one
>   Choose how Yahoo! contacts you

**Sign-In and Security**

> ```
> Change your password
> Update password-reset info
> Create a sign-in seal 
> Manage/Create your OpenID
> Manage Other Accounts to Sign-in
> Manage Apps and Website Connections
> Change sign-in settings
> View your recent sign-in activity
> ```
>
> **Account Settings**
>
> Manage your Yahoo! aliases      **<---- THIS ONE**
>     View/Update your saved locations
>
> Notifications and Subscriptions
>
> > View your Yahoo! premium services.
> >       Update newsletter & marketing options

The answer here worked for me
http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100926044452AA8gPBz

> Click on "Account Info" which is in the drop down menu (on your email
>   page) by your username where it says "Hi, ____".
>
> Sign into your Yahoo Account. Go to the section "Account Settings" and
>   click on "Manage your Yahoo Aliases".
>
> Click on "Add an Alias". Type your alias in the box provided and then
>   click on "Save". You can have up to 6 aliases. Click on "Close when
>   finished".
>
> In the Messenger Pane, click on "Contacts" and then "Add a Contact"
>   and add your aliases to your Yahoo Messenger. (You don't need to do
>   this).
>
> When you IM someone, pick the name you want to use in the drop down
>   box above where you type next to "Send As".
>
> Here is a link telling you how to use one of your aliases when you
>   enter Chat Rooms.
>
> http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?y=PROD_MS…
>
> Alternatively, you could just change your current name by changing
>   your Contact Details. To do this, click on "Messenger" in the top left
>   hand corner of the Messenger Window. Click on "My Contact Details" and
>   change your name in the top boxes and change your name under
>   "Nickname". Click on "Save and Close" at the bottom.